# Windows App Certification Failed for Sqlite plugin

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, mvvmcross

I tried to validate a simple Windows store project with [Windows App Certification Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/jj572486.aspx) but verification failed in '**Supported API test**'.

I have tried to add also all plugins to see where we could have problems with Windows certification and i found that also 'Performance test' failed in the '**Performance launch**' process.

Here the details regardin Sqlite 'Supported APIs':

> API sqlite3_bind_blob in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_bind_double in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_bind_int in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_bind_int64 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_bind_null in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_bind_parameter_index in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_bind_text16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_busy_timeout in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_changes in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_close in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_blob in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_bytes in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_count in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_double in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_int in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_int64 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_name in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_name16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_text in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_text16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_column_type in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_config in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_errmsg16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_finalize in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_last_insert_rowid in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_open in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_open16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_open_v2 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_prepare_v2 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_reset in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.
>   API sqlite3_step in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll calls this API.

And here the 'Performance launch test' failed details:

> The Native Image Generator failed due to long file path for file C:\Users\babba\Desktop\MvvmCrossTestOk\Test.Store\bin\Release\AppX\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Accelerometer.WindowsStore.dll
>   The Native Image Generator failed due to long file path for file C:\Users\babba\Desktop\MvvmCrossTestOk\Test.Store\bin\Release\AppX\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.WindowsStore.dll
>   The Native Image Generator failed due to long file path for file C:\Users\babba\Desktop\MvvmCrossTestOk\Test.Store\bin\Release\AppX\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ReflectionEx.WindowsStore.dll
>   The Native Image Generator failed due to long file path for file C:\Users\babba\Desktop\MvvmCrossTestOk\Test.Store\bin\Release\AppX\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.WindowsStore.dll
>   The Native Image Generator failed due to long file path for file C:\Users\babba\Desktop\MvvmCrossTestOk\Test.Store\bin\Release\AppX\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ThreadUtils.WindowsStore.dll
>   The Native Image Generator failed due to long file path for file C:\Users\babba\Desktop\MvvmCrossTestOk\Test.Store\bin\Release\AppX\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.WindowsStore.dll
>   The Native Image Generator failed due to long file path for file C:\Users\babba\Desktop\MvvmCrossTestOk\Test.Store\bin\Release\AppX\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.WebBrowser.WindowsStore.dll

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add more tags to questions like this - eg winstore, sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few store apps have shipped to the store with this plugin - but because of Microsoft's native sqlite support you do have to ship separate assemblies for each platform.

> long file path for file ...

try a shorter path - eg use C:/projects rather than C:/users....

> unsupported apis

make sure you include the correct version of sqlite with each platform - x86, x64 and arm. There's an example block for platform dependent csproj in the middle of http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/396720

in theory this is possible to do via the nuget package, but it's non-trivial and no-one's contributed it yet